# How to configure Castle Windsor to dynamically pick the provider based upon arguments (other than "name") supplied to Resolve()

Tags: castle-windsor, typed-factory-facility

I am trying to learn how to use Castle Windsor IoC and am having some difficulties understanding how to configure some objects that I need to resolve dynamically.  Basically, I have several implementations of IDataSource, and I need to choose the implementation to use based upon how a particular "data source" has been configured.  So I might have quite alot of data sources configured to use one of the 3 implementations.  My expectation is that the dependant code will take a dependency on a factory method which will give them the correct IDataSource when it is provided with the "data source id" along with the dependencies the data source implementations require (an IPrincipal).

I am struggling with how to correctly write the registration delegate for Windsor.  Below is roughly what I've got.  I'm trying to use the `DynamicParameters` method (which may not be the correct thing to use) to perform the logic which figures out which implementation to use and then calling `Resolve` to pull out that specific version.  But I do not know how to return the resolved object, since `DynamicParameters` is expecting a `ComponentReleasingDelegate`, which I assume means it should be something like `return k => { k.ReleaseComponent(dataSource); }`.  But then how do I yield the dataSource I've acquired back to the container for it to return to the caller?

```
struct DataSourceInfo {
  string Id;
  string ProviderType;
}

interface ICatalog : IDictionary<string /* Id */, DataSourceInfo> {
  /* ... */
}

class Catalog : ICatalog {
  /* implement dictionary which looks up DataSourceInfo from their string id */
}

interface IDataSource { /* ... */ }

class Source1 : IDataSource {
  Source1(string id, IPrincipal principal) { /* ... */ }
}

class Source2 : IDataSource {
  Source2(string id, IPrincipal principal) { /* ... */ }
}

/* ... */
/* ... inside Windsor configuration section */
container.Register(Component.For<ICatalog>().LifeStyle.Singleton.ImplementedBy<Catalog>());

// Default service provider is a factory method which uses the string (data source id)
// and looks up the DataSourceInfo from the ICatalog.  It then uses info.ProviderType
// to request IoC to resolve that specific implementation and passes in "id" and "principal"
// to be used to resolve the dependencies of the implementation
container.Register(Component.For<IDataSource>().LifeStyle.Transient
  .DynamicParameters((kernel, context, args) => {
      if (args == null || !args.Contains("id") || !(args["id"] is string)) throw ApplicationException("bad args");

      var id = (string)args["id"];
      var catalog = kernel.Resolve<ICatalog>();
      DataSourceInfo info;
      try { info = catalog[id]; } finally { kernel.ReleaseComponent(catalog); }

      // Now resolve the actual IDataSource
      var dataSource = kernel.Resolve<IDataSource>(info.ProviderType, args);

      // How do I return dataSource???
    });

// Now register the actual implementations
container.Register(Component.For<IDataSource>().LifeStyle.Transient.ImplementedBy<Source1>().Named("Source1"));
container.Register(Component.For<IDataSource>().LifeStyle.Transient.ImplementedBy<Source2>().Named("Source2"));

/* ... */
/* some application startup code which configures some data sources */
class AppConfigurer {
  AppConfigurer(ICatalog catalog) {
    catalog["sourceA"] = new DataSourceInfo() { Id = "sourceA", ProviderType = "Source1" }; // data sourceA is provided by Source1 class
    catalog["sourceB"] = new DataSourceInfo() { Id = "sourceB", ProviderType = "Source2" }; // data sourceB is provided by Source2 class
    catalog["sourceC"] = new DataSourceInfo() { Id = "sourceC", ProviderType = "Source2" }; // data sourceC is provided by Source2 class
    catalog["sourceD"] = new DataSourceInfo() { Id = "sourceD", ProviderType = "Source2" }; // data sourceD is provided by Source2 class
    catalog["sourceE"] = new DataSourceInfo() { Id = "sourceE", ProviderType = "Source1" }; // data sourceE is provided by Source1 class        
  }
}

// Here is where I actually want to use IDataSources, and I do not want to know all the business about IDataSourceInfo.  I just know a dataSourceId and an IPrincipal and want to get an IDataSource to work with.
class Dependant {
  Dependant (Func<string, IPrincipal, IDataSource> factory) {
    var sourceA = factory("sourceA", somePrincipal); // sourceA.GetType() == typeof(Source1)
    var sourceB = factory("sourceB", somePrincipal); // sourceB.GetType() == typeof(Source2)
    var sourceC = factory("sourceC", somePrincipal); // sourceC.GetType() == typeof(Source2)
  }
}
```

Edit: by switching from `DynamicParameters` to `UsingFactoryMethod` I am able to do what I want.  But I keep thinking this is wrong because now if I do `container.ResolveAll()` I'd really like it to skip the factory method but I don't know how to make it do that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a custom component type selector and decide which component to load based on that?

[Typed Factory Facility - interface-based factories](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md)